# Archive data from "sheet1" to next blank row of "sheet2"

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to archive data from "sheet1" to "sheet2". It overwrites existing data in the "sheet2" rows from the previous archive exercise.

How do I have it seek the next blank row vs. overwriting existing data?

I have two header rows so it should commence with row 3.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Archive()
    Dim lr As Long, I As Long, rowsArchived As Long
    Dim unionRange As Range

    Sheets("sheet1").Unprotect Password:="xxxxxx"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheets("sheet1")
        lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For I = 3 To lr 'sheets all have headers that are 2 rows
            If .Range("AB" & I) = "No" Then
                If (unionRange Is Nothing) Then
                    Set unionRange = .Range(I & ":" & I)
                Else
                    Set unionRange = Union(unionRange, .Range(I & ":" & I))
                End If
            End If
        Next I
    End With

    rowsArchived = 0
    If (Not (unionRange Is Nothing)) Then
        For I = 1 To unionRange.Areas.Count
            rowsArchived = rowsArchived + unionRange.Areas(I).Rows.Count
        Next I
        unionRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet2").Range("A3")
        unionRange.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    Sheets("sheet2").Protect Password:="xxxxxx"

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Operation Completed.  Total Rows Archived: " & rowsArchived
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
unionRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet2").Range("A3")
```

... to,

```
with worksheets("sheet2")
    unionRange.Copy _
      Destination:=.Cells(.rows.count, 1).end(xlup).offset(1, 0)
end with
```

This is like starting at the bottom row of the worksheet (e.g. A1048576) and tapping [ctrl+[↑] then selecting the cell directly below it.

The [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) isn't absolutely necessary but it shortens the code line enough to see it all without scolling across. `unionRange` has been definied by parent worksheet and cell range so there is no ambiguity here.

Comment: Appears to work, but pastes over my row2 header and any subsequent runs of the code overlaps the last non-blank row in sheet2.

Comment: ... so if you go to A1048576 on Sheet2 and tap [ctrl]+[↑] then tap [↓] you would not end up in the next available row..?

Comment: It goes to row A2 and then back down to A1048576 when I tap [ctrl]+[↑] then tap [↓].

Comment: a) it sounds like you are holding [ctrl] down when you  tap [↓] b) it also sounds like you do not have anything below A2 but if you do not hold the [ctrl] key down then [↓] should get you to A3 which is where you want to be.

Comment: Closed Excel, reopened file and re-entered the change and it is working as expected now. Unsure what the issue was?

Comment: *<sigh>* sometimes a VBA environment becomes so unstable though testing different scenarios that a complete cold restart is necessary to put things back in order (and even then sometimes not).

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose the following "refactoring"

```
Option Explicit

Sub Archive()
Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

Set sht1 = Sheets("sheet1")
Set sht2 = Sheets("sheet2")

sht1.Unprotect Password:="xxxxxx"

With sht1.Columns("AB").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(, 1) '<== change the offset as per your need to point to whatever free column you may have
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=if(RC[-1]=""NO"","""",1)"
    .Value = .Value
    With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        .EntireRow.Copy Destination:=sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        MsgBox "Operation Completed.  Total Rows Archived: " & .Cells.Count
    End With
    .ClearContents
End With

sht2.Protect Password:="xxxxxx"

End Sub
```

just choose a "free" column in "Sheet1" to be used as a helper one and that'll be cleared before exiting macro. In the above code I assumed it's one column to the right of "AB"

Answer (score 0):

The following approach worked for me! I'm using a button to trigger macro.
Every time it takes the last row and append it to new sheet like a history. Actually you can make a loop for every value inside your sheet.

```
Sub copyProcess()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim copySheet As Worksheet
  Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
  Dim source_last_row As Long 'last master sheet row
  source_last_row = 0

  source_last_row = Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

  Set copySheet = Worksheets("master")
  Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("alpha")

  copySheet.Range("A" & source_last_row, "C" & source_last_row).copy

  pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial 
  xlPasteValues
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```